# mysql and php - export specific row

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

Hello I have a test table with name mytable and with following data

```
id  name   surname
==================
1   sotos  val
2   john   rik
3   peter  ask
```

How can id export for example the second row in mysql using php knowing the id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.name,
       t.surname
  FROM MYTABLE t
 WHERE t.id = mysql_real_escape_string($id)
```

Reference:

- [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
- [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

### PHP

```
<?php

  $query = "SELECT t.id,
                   t.name,
                   t.surname
              FROM MYTABLE t
             WHERE t.id = mysql_real_escape_string($id)";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['surname'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: What is the `MYTABLE` keyword for?

Comment: @Christian Mann: That's the OP stated the table name is - "...I have a test table with name mytable...", but you can change it to suit.

Comment: Ah. The `t` is solely an alias? Huh. Didn't know you could skip the `AS` keyword. Good to know!

Comment: @Christian Mann: Yep, `t` is a table alias.  The `AS` keyword is optional on most databases for both table and column aliases.

Answer (score 2):

If by export you mean dump data into ready-to-use SQL query try this one:

```
$sql_query = shell_exec('x:\path\to\mysqldump.exe -t --compact -u DB_USERNAME --password=DB_PASSWORD DB_NAME mytable --where="id = 2"');
```

Will produce something like:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES(2,'john','rik');
```

Comment: Judging from OP reputation, previous questions and website provided in profile, he has basic knowledge how to get data from mysql in php. OP has not specified what does he expects as output, so I provided my interpretation of mysql **export** using php.